# Install local Minikube Hue on k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, hue

I'm trying to install hue by helm on local kubernetes, using minikube context. Installation go well, but at the end I have to find hue running on http://minikube:32284, but on the browser I obtain "Impossible to find IP Address of the minikube server". Whitch is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have only to do:
**minikube service hue**

This is because my cluster k8s don't run in local, but run in virtual environment created by docker. So when I search in local I can't find minikube. The command minikube service create a tunnel that expose the service to the external environment